# How can I make the player jump in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello can you help to make the player jump

also how to make the player crouch?

this is my move script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform cam;
    public float speed = 6f;
    public float turnsmoothT = 0.1f;
    float turnsmoothV;

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnsmoothV, turnsmoothT);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
            Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Have you tried anything? I mean there is even an exmaple for it in the [API of `CharacterController.Move`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) ...

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.

Comment: please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform cam;
    public float speed = 6f;
    public float turnsmoothT = 0.1f;
    private float turnsmoothV;
    private bool jumping = false;
    private float moveDirectionY = 0;
    private float gravity = 9.81f;

    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;
        Vector3 moveDir = Vector3.zero;
        if (jumping && controller.isGrounded)
        {
            jumping = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !jumping && controller.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirectionY = 3f;
            jumping = true;
        }
        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnsmoothV, turnsmoothT);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
            moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
        }
        moveDirectionY -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        moveDir.y = moveDirectionY;
        controller.Move(moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```